# loop through sql in r

Tags: sql, r, loops

I have a sql code and want to put a for loop on it

This is my temptation for loop and it does not work:

```
list <- c(58362, 58384)
for (l in list){
"SELECT Top 3 G.MupolygonWktWgs84 as geom, l as mukey from SDA_Get_MupolygonWktWgs84_from_Mukey('462594') as G" }
```

This is the right way for sql:

```
"SELECT Top 3 G.MupolygonWktWgs84 as geom, '58362' as mukey from SDA_Get_MupolygonWktWgs84_from_Mukey('462594') as G"
```

Can anybody help me to figure out how to write this for loop?

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to convert numbers to strings, and it worked:

```
list <- c(58362, 58384)
for (l in list) {
 q <- paste("SELECT G.MupolygonWktWgs84 as geom, '",l,"' as mukey from 
SDA_Get_MupolygonWktWgs84_from_Mukey('",l,"') as G",sep="")
}
```

Comment: If numbers derive from user input consider [parameterization](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` and an appropriate ODBC library to accomplish this. But you'll need to define your `con` with the various settings.

`list <- c(58362, 58384)
result <- list()
for (l in list){
result[l] <- dbGetQuery(con, paste("SELECT Top 3 G.MupolygonWktWgs84 as geom,",  l, "as mukey from SDA_Get_MupolygonWktWgs84_from_Mukey('462594') as G")) }`